What is the difference between Virtually indexed, physically tagged (VIPT) and Physically indexed, physically tagged (PIPT) mapping?
In VIPT, the index comes from the page offset part of the virutal address(VA), wiki says its advantage is the cache line can be looked up in parallel with the TLB translation. So my question is, since page offset is same for both VA and PA then why can't PIPT starts the look up early like VIPT?
(or  given a VA, doesn't both VIPT and PIPT produces the same index and tag values?)
I read couple of lectures but couldn't clear my doubts.
